# WPF change mainwindow to different windows/forms depending which is the current open "Main Window" of the application

Tags: wpf

I have an application that has multiple windows. Some are older Forms but the most important ones are WPF.

It should be impossible for a user to open the application multiple times. Instead if launched a second time the current opened window of the already running application should be put into front (depending if its minimized or just behind other windows). Then the second launched application will close itself after doing this.

That's what I tried but it works only on the first (login) window of the application.

ProcessID is the processid of the already opened application **not** the second one.

```
Dim proc As Process = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessID)
ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, SHOW_WINDOW.SW_NORMAL)

 Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,ByVal nCmdShow As SHOW_WINDOW) As Boolean
```

What's the best approach to the problem? Should I change the MainWindowHandle during runtime depending on which window (administration, settings, workspace, countless dialogs,...)

If yes, how?

This was not much help for me or I didn't understand how to apply it to my project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/how-to-get-set-main-application-window?view=netdesktop-7.0

If not, how is it done better?

Comment: Use mutex to check if another instance is running and sendmessage to tell the other instance it needs to maximise and .Activate() whichever window is the last one opened. That will be last in the list of windows.  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1017834/How-to-Send-Data-from-One-Process-to-Another-in-Cs  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f9f215/how-to-restrict-the-application-to-just-one-instance/

Comment: Something like var lastwindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Last();  But I'm not sure without checking if that'll get you mainwindow.

Comment: If your entry point is winforms then you won't have an application object. You'll need to write some code which updates some sort of static/global variable with a reference to the latest window opened.  Call it in the contentrendered of each wpf window.

Comment: Thank you, i hoped that i can do that easier without app-app communication... the winforms have a very low priority. Will try that next week.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PInvoke to use Win32 API to find the window instance and bring it to the front. Using this approach also eliminates the identification of processes. Instead we are now looking for window instances.

The following example tries to find an existing window instance by window title. If it finds one, we shutdown the current instance and bring the already active instance to the foreground. If no window was found we continue to show a new window. The example requires to launch the main window manually by registering an `Application.Startup` event handler (in place of setting the `Application.StartupUri`).

**C#**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

  private void OnApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    var mainWindowTitle = mainWindow.Title;
    if (TryFindWindow(mainWindowTitle))
    {
      Shutdown();
    }
    else
    {
      mainWindow.Show();
    }
  }

  public static bool TryFindWindow(string windowName)
  {
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, windowName);
    return SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
  }
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Public Partial Class App
    Inherits Application

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)>
    Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean

    Private Sub OnApplicationStartup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StartupEventArgs)
        Dim mainWindow = New MainWindow()
        Dim mainWindowTitle = mainWindow.Title

        If TryFindWindow(mainWindowTitle) Then
            Shutdown()
        Else
            mainWindow().Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function TryFindWindow(ByVal windowName As String) As Boolean
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, windowName)
        Return SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Getting the other processid(s) is not the problem. I do that reliably already by getting my own processid and checking the processes of the same user with same name to see if there is another processid thats different. My problem is that i want to put the the currently active window on "top" if its behind other windows or minimized.

Comment: I see. Sorry for confusing your question. I have updated my answer to give you an example.